# youtube gdata timeout

Tags: php, timeout, youtube-api

I have a Problem with the GDATA API for Youtube.

Without making changes at my php Settings or the code I can not Access YouTube any more via PHP API.

Creating a new Zend_Gdata_YouTube Object and Loading Video data results in a 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' exception with the following message:

> Unable to Connect to tcp://gdata.youtube.com:80. Error #110:
>   Connection timed out' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:688 Stack
>   trace: #0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata.php(221):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL) #1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(875):
>   Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array) #2
>   /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(763):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->get('http://gdata.yo...', NULL) #3
>   /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(220):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...',
>   NULL) #4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata.php(187):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->getEntry('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...')
>   '#5' /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php(293):
>   Zend_Gdata->getEntry('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...')

I know this is a timeout. But what can cause this timeout? Since I do not mind having Change anything on the connectivity Settings of the Server and a ping to gdata.youtube.com just works perfectly.

Addionally  I want to say, that the Systems runs not on a shared hosting plattform so there is no hoster doing whatever he want to do - sytem changes are performed by me personally.

Comment: Can you add the code around this line `/usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:688`?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on the YouTube API server side of things that would cause a connection to be completely refused from any client. Even if, for some reason, you client's traffic violated some quota limit or was blocked due to anti-DoS protection (and I'm not implying that's the case), we still would return a valid HTTP response to your request.

So, I can say with some confidence that whatever the issue is, it's not due to the YouTube API server. The most likely culprit is a networking issue somewhere between your server and the YouTube API. Standard network troubleshooting procedures are in order.

Comment: Yes indeed, it was not a Problem of the API.  After some more Investigation I figuered out that it was releated to ipv6 and my Server is not able to handle ipv6 to any Google Server. 
The more interesting Thing is: He is only not able to connect to Google Server via ipv6 - v4 works and non Google Servers and v6 work also

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing all the google links in my upload script to be secure connections.

For example, I changed

```
http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
```

to

```
https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
```